# Geocoder gem testing ip request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, development-environment, rails-geocoder, test-environments

I want to test the following line in my **view** :

**app/views/products/index.html.erb**

```rb
<%= render @products %>
```

**app/views/products/_product.html.erb**

```rb
<td><%= distance_between(@current_location, product.location) %></td>
```

The `@products` and `@current_location` are defined in the associated **controller** :

```rb
def index
  @products = Product.all
end
```

And :

```rb
unless @current_location
  if !current_user.nil?
    @current_location = current_user.location
  else
    @current_location = request.location
  end
end
```

The `distance_between` method is defined in the **location helper** :

```rb
def distance_between(here, there)
  t('location.distance.kilometre', count: here.distance_to(there, :km).round(1)) 
end
```

So, there is my **test** :

```rb
let(:current_location) { request.location }
it { should have_selector('td', text: distance_between(product.location, current_location))}
```

And the error message :

```rb
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('td', text: distance_between(product.location, current_location))}
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `location' for nil:NilClass
 Shared Example Group: "product's informations" called from ./spec/requests/product_index_page_spec.rb:119
 # ./spec/requests/product_index_page_spec.rb:118:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/support/products/index.rb:31:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

In production, the geocoder gem can request the ip of the user, and render his location, with `request.location`, but I don't know how to do that in test or development environment. Can you help me to correct my code ?

Comment: Hi Flo,
Are you sure you are showing us the right test ?

in your test it is
      request.location

and in your error it is
      current_location

According to the error shown, it looks as if product is nil in your test.

Comment: OK, thanks, I corrected it (I wanted to simplify the example, but I forgot to correct the error accordingly...)

Comment: Where are you defining the product instance that you are using in distance_between(product.location ?

Comment: Hi Nico, I updated my question.

Comment: Hey, are you still stuck with this error ? In that case can you please show the whole file containing the following lines:

let(:current_location) { request.location }
it { should have_selector('td', text: distance_between(product.location, current_location))}

Comment: In fact, I understood where the problem was. In a development environment, I don't have a real IP address, so `request.location` can't give me a location...

Comment: Is that the whole test? Are you constructing the request somewhere?